How to prove $(\partial^2 P)/(\partial V \partial T) \leq 0$? (Question about Griffiths’ 1965 Thermodynamic Inequalities and Apparent Contradictions)
I am currently studying a paper by Griffiths (1965b) on thermodynamic inequalities and have encountered some conceptual difficulties with the formulation presented therein. I’m hoping to get some clarification on these points.The screenshots of the paper, the DOI and the link are provided below.
Griffiths introduces the inequality:
$$\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial V^2} = \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial V \partial T} \geq 0, \tag{1}$$
which is stated to hold on the critical isotherm. Additionally, he defines a modified entropy function:
$$S^*(T,V) = -\frac{\partial F^*}{\partial T} = S - S_c - \Gamma_c (V - V_c), \tag{2}$$
and a modified derivative function:
$$\Gamma^*(T,V) = \frac{\partial P^*}{\partial T} = \frac{\partial S^*}{\partial V} = \Gamma - \Gamma_c. \tag{3}$$
From these definitions, Griffiths asserts that on the critical isotherm ($T = T_c$), the condition ($S^* < 0$) holds ((4)). However, evaluating the definitions at the critical point $(T_c, V_c)$, we find:
$$S^*(T_c, V_c) = 0, \quad (\frac{\partial S^*}{\partial V})_{T_c, V_c} = 0. \tag{5}$$
Considering the inequality (1), which suggests that the (S-V) curve is convex downwards, it would imply that:
$$S^* \geq 0, \tag{6}$$
This seems to contradict assertion (4). Many of Griffiths’ conclusions in the paper appear to rely on (4), leading me to question the validity of (1). Despite my efforts, I’ve been unable to reconcile these points or prove the assertion myself.
Could someone provide insights into whether there is a misinterpretation or error in my understanding, or if indeed there might be an inconsistency in the formulation as presented by Griffiths?
Here's the link of the paper:
https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/43/6/1958/79114/Ferromagnets-and-Simple-Fluids-near-the-Critical
DOI:
https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1697060
Here's the screenshots of the paper:



The title of the question has an inequality that’s the reverse of the inequality in the rest of the question. Is this a typo or is it intentional?

@Chemomechanics, that is indeed intentional. While we can demonstrate that $\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial V \partial T} \geq 0$ by employing the isothermal compressibility $\kappa_T$ and the critical exponent $\gamma$, there appears to be an inconsistency in our findings. Specifically, if $\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial V \partial T} \geq 0$ holds true, it implies that $S^* \geq 0$, which contradicts the assertions made by the author. Consequently, I am seeking to validate the contrary proposition.
